# Area Menus, Tcode and Program Name in SAP

Tags: sap-gui, sap-basis

Pl. provide tables name, from where I can get relation between Area menus , Program names and Transaction codes.

Answer (score 1):

Table :

- TSTC will give you the correspondance between a SAP programme (+dynpro) and a transaction code.
- TRDIR contains more informations on the program itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL trace (ST05) while opening an area menu in SE43N. This will give you a list of tables that are read in the process. This can be applied to other areas of interest as well.